# .NET MVC - Client not always downloading file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a button that when pressed should send a file to the client. Problem it is that if client is idling for more than 5 minute in the page and then click the button, it doesn't download anymore.

Web app is hosted in IIS, might be the problem with some configuration in IIS?

That's how i return the file

```
return File(byteArray, "application/octet-stream", "test.test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methods:

1. Open "IIS Manager"
2. Select "Application Pool" the instance you want to manage
3. Select "Advanced settings"
4. Under "(General)" and set "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning", which
   means the application pool keep the ASP.NET application run always

Also, If you want the ASP.NET application be loaded automatically, you can follow this:

1. Open "IIS Manager"
2. Select the application you want to manage
3. Select "Advanced settings"
4. Under "(General)" and set "Preload Enabled" to "true", which means
   the applicaton will be loaded automatically after its deployment.